# retrieve values having same foreign key id

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to retrieve all the value from a field having same foreign key value , then I have to add those values and display it in the response.

```
status = models.CharField(
    max_length=50, 
    choices=WALLET_STATUS_CHOICES, 
    default='cash')
merchant = models.ForeignKey(
    merchant_models.Merchant, 
    db_index=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='merchant12', 
    null=True,
    blank=True)
cheque_no = models.CharField(
    max_length=100, 
    null=True, 
    blank=True)
cheque_date= models.DateTimeField()
recharge_amount=models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=0.0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.name)
```

I have to get all the recharge values having same merchant id then I have to add those value and have to display.i have to get this sum in "merchant/id " url.is there any way in django?

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose your model name is EXA and merchant_id is the id of merchant,then.

```
merchant_obj = Merchant.objects.get(id=merchant_id)
objects = EXA.objects.filter(merchant=merchant_obj)
total_recharge = 0
for object in objects:
    total_recharge += object.recharge_amount
print total_recharge
```

Or you can use aggregate

```
from django.db.models import Sum

merchant_obj = Merchant.objects.get(id=merchant_id)
total_recharge = EXA.objects.filter(merchant=merchant_obj).aggregate(Sum('recharge_amount'))
print total_recharge
```

Comment: return  render(request, 'app_name/display.html', {'total_amount',total_recharge})  or for ajax response = {'data':total_recharge}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))

Comment: thank you...both method works well@PatDuJour and Arpit Singh

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model name is Transaction.
If you have access to the merchant object somewhere in your logic:

```
qs = Transaction.objects.filter(merchant=merchant)
```

Or if you know the foreign key id for the merchant_id:

```
qs = Transaction.objects.filter(merchant_id=merchant_id)
```

Then you can use the [aggregate and Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) function in Django:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
qs.aggregate(Sum('recharge_amount'))
```

OR all in line:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_recharge = Transaction.objects.filter(
    merchant_id=merchant_id
).aggregate(
    Sum('recharge_amount'))
```